# In MySQL database, Can we create an column in a table using ALTER which auto assigns its name. (like ID auto increment)

Tags: mysql, xampp

In MySQL database, Can we create an column in a table using ALTER which auto assigns its name whenever we press a 'add' button in webpage.

It's like..  creating a column and auto assigning it's name whenever we press 'add' button. 
So, there will be ID, column1,column2,column3.. and so on..

Apologies for poor questioning, newbie here.

Any response is appreciated.

Comment: The only automatic assignment is auto increment. There's nothing similar for string columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 1 auto increment column per table and it must be defined as a key. If the table you're altering doesn't already have an auto-increment column, you can add one like this:

```
alter table mytable add column id int unsigned primary key auto_increment first;
```

If you are asking about assigning a default value automatically and retroactively (to existing rows), you can do that too.

```
alter table mytable add column status_type varchar(32) not null default 'pending';
```

Comment: I m sorry but my question regards to creating a column and auto assigning it's name whenever we press 'add' button. So, there will be ID, column1,column2,column3,.. and so on..

Comment: Is the value dynamic or hard-coded? I updated my answer to show an example of a varchar column with a default value.

Comment: Ok, see the 2nd example in my answer. It should work for you.

Comment: So, with that code , my table will have a  new column..  But what about it's name..  I would like to have it autoassigned..

Comment: Sorry. I'm still trying to understand your use case. Are you looking to create dynamic column names with hardcoded default values?

Comment: My apologies mate, i dont know much about dynamic or hard coded.. But i m sure of that i want its name as auto assigned as column 1, column2, Column3, soo on... Hope you understood.. Thanks by the way..

Comment: What you're describing is dynamic column names. This isn't the way relational databases are designed to be used. Consider re-designing your system such that lists of elements that can grow to arbitrary sizes are implemented by adding new *rows* to a table, not new *columns*. The columns in a table should remain fixed (not counting schema design changes).

Comment: Can you take a look at this one mate..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330887/slide-up-slide-down-is-not-working-for-selected-table-rows-from-db?noredirect=1#comment65993670_39330887